# Missing session data after paypal express checkout

Tags: php, session, opencart, paypal

Our opencart based store is using the paypal express checkout and about 25% of the paypal express orders are expericing issues.

The problem seems to be when they return to the website after paypal, their session data is missing so all the details of their cart has gone.

To try and see what could be causing it, when they return to the site (normally through payment/pp_express/expressReturn) and the session data does not have the paypal/cart details I've logged details of most of the superglobals.
Their session is always:

```
Array
(
    [category] => desktop
    [language] => en
    [currency] => GBP
    [cart] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Sometimes when they return their cookies are empty, other times the language, currency  & tracking are there.

After investigating further it looked like the session was being lost because of the way it was being redirected:

```
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgiâ€‘bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . $result['TOKEN'].'&useraction=commit');
```

So before every header redirect I added

```
session_write_close();
```

The problem actually seemed to be eased a bit but it is still happening.

The server uses memcache and my final thought is that perhaps it is low on memory and their session is lost - but I would imagine we would see frequent logout issues throughout our sites if that were the case.

Comment: Are these signed in users that you are using a `session_start()` with at some point? And if so, you are saying that their session is not being detected when the user gets bounced back to your server?  (just trying to understand in a bit more detail what you are doing and facing)

Comment: Yes - the session is started much earlier but when I log sessiondata/post/get/cookies/server in the paypal express checkout there is no mention of the a session id

Comment: Are you using the default PayPal Express Checkout payment extension that comes with default OpenCart installation or some third-party one? There should be no issue with the default payment option. I have set up many eshops using this one exactly and never experienced such behavior. If it is some third-party extension then contact its developer(s) asking for support.

Comment: The OpenCart version is 1.5.4 and the PayPal express is modified (things such as recurring profiles have been removed) from a later version 1.5.6.3)
I haven't been able to recreate the issue, it happens on multiple browsers & devices also

Answer (score 1):

In my excperience it is bad practice to use Sessions for displaying order data after returning from payment gateways.

Most payment gateways (inlcuding PayPal) let you pass on an OrderID or other custom variables that will be passed back on Success / Failure. You can generally follow this procedure:

1. Save order to database, retrieve orderID
2. Redirect to payment gateway. Pass orderID to the payment gateway.
3. On success / failure read order from database using the orderID sent back by the payment gateway

Comment: I don't want to rewrite the paypal express module but would serializing the cart and storing it in the database then if the session is missing recreate the cart from the stored version work acceptably?

Comment: That's basically what I'm suggesting to do. But you need an ID to identify the serialized cart in your database. You can send that ID to paypal and it will return it on the success or error page. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349151/paypal-ipn-returning-a-shopping-cart-or-order-id-for-post-processing for more details. In this case you don't need sessions anymore.

Comment: OpenCart already works like this. If the customer starts the checkout process and walks down to the "Confirm" step before submitting - the order is already created and stored in the DB (in OC world we call it *dummy order* as it has not any status yet thus is not visible even in administration). After submitting the payment gateway is invoked - in this case the user is redirected to PayPal with this dummy order's ID and other information provided to PayPal. After he is redirected back the payment's gateway `callback` method is called making sure the order is updated with correct status.

Comment: Afterwards the user is redirected to the success page where all the order and cart session is cleared - but at this point the order shall already exist with the status *Confirmed* (if everything went well with the payment).